# how to manually install net-tools on WSL2 without internet connection?

Tags: wsl-2

I am trying to debug a WSL2 installation which will not connect to internet. how to manually install net-tools on WSL2 without internet connection? My WSL is Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: A good thought, to be sure, but I don't think this is going to yield much info for you under WSL.  The network is actually fully under the control of Hyper-V (at least a slimmed-down version for WSL2).  `\init`, WSL's PID1 startup process, brings up the Linux network stack and connects it to the vNIC in Hyper-V.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that this is an old post that got bumped.  It's unlikely that you are still investigating this, but leaving the comment for future readers who might be thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/net-tools/download

Find folder where your WSL / WSL 2 has data - https://askubuntu.com/a/759885

Copy .deb file into /tmp (example)

Run: `sudo apt-get install /tmp/net-tools_*_amd64.deb`

Comment: Just a heads-up that the `\\wsl$\<distro>` share *may* not work when the network is down inside WSL2.  If it doesn't, then there's probably still a way to get the package in via the `wsl` command and piping. Not at my computer at the moment to get the right incantation.  Also be aware of PowerShell  limitations piping binary data to non-PowerShell commands if you have to go that route.  If you need help with it, tag me in a reply and I'll look at it when I get back to the computer.